# My Django secret key is in an environment variable but I can't do syncdb

Tags: django, virtualenv

I'm setting up a Django project with different files for local and production settings. I can confirm that my Django secret key is successfully in an environment variable in virtualenv and when I do runserver I get no error.  However when I try manage.py syncdb I get

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

I don't understand why I can successfully browse to the site after runserver but I can't sync the database.  When I run env I can see that the secret key is there and in my base settings file (imported into local settings) I am doing this:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('MY_SECRET_KEY')
```

Any help debugging this would be greatly appreciated.

Euan

Comment: How about `SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('MY_SECRET_KEY', 'fallback')`

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work I'm afraid.

Comment: OK.  I fixed this by running syncdb passing my local settings file to the settings variable like this:    python manage.py syncdb --settings=myapp.settings.local  Can anyone possibly explain why I had to do this?

Comment: @EuanMillar How do you run `runserver`? and where is `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` pointing at?

Comment: When I do runserver I also have to point the settings file to my local version.  But in my wsgi file I am doing 'os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings.local")'

Comment: @EuanMillar is this `SECRET_KEY` used by any specific library?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the runserver command is working while syncdb isn't, but you can sort it out by adding a environment variable for DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in the same way you did for the SECRET_KEY. The only difference is that you don't need to reference DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE within the django code anywhere. I'm running my own setup in exactly that way and the only problem I run into is forgetting to change the settings module when I switch between projects :-)

EDIT: I didn't realise that you were adding --settings=myapp.settings.local to `runserver` as well as `syncdb`. The reason you need to do this is that you are using settings on a different path from the default so python can't find them. Also, although you set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in the wsgi file, this is only fired when the site is accessed via your webserver. When running a manage command the wsgi file is ignored (AFAIK) so adding DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to your environment variables in the same way as SECRET_KEY makes your settings file available to the manage command.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks.  The annoying thing is that I'm doing that already in my wsgi file:  `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "rbsmortgages.settings.local")`  Is that right?

Comment: That's fine for when the site is being accessed through apache (or whatever webserver you use), but the wsgi file isn't accessed when running a manage command (AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat similar situation here, using virtualenv running an outer script which involves django models.

To make this work please make sure:
Your `sys.path` list has a path to your virtualenv site-packages. For me it's: `sys.path.append('/home/user/.virtualenvs/Project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')`

Your django settings variable is added to `os.environ`. Eg: `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Project.settings")`